# bash: poetry: command not found when I try to install it with cygwin

Tags: bash, cygwin

I try to install [spotdl](https://spotdl.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#installing-ffmpeg) on Windows but is very complicated, poetry package has always problem to install
So I try to use **cygwin** to install it, but unsuccessfully
1.
These are commands to install:

```
git clone https://github.com/spotDL/spotify-downloader && cd spotify-downloader
```

2. 

Install rustup

```
curl --proto '=https' --tlsv1.2 -sSf https://sh.rustup.rs | sh

pip install poetry
poetry install
python3 scripts/build.py
```

3. 

**Relevant error is this**

```
Collecting rpds-py>=0.7.1 (from jsonschema<5.0.0,>=4.10.0->poetry)
  Using cached rpds_py-0.9.2.tar.gz (16 kB)
  Installing build dependencies ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × pip subprocess to install build dependencies did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [57 lines of output]
      Collecting maturin<2.0,>=1.0
        Using cached maturin-1.1.0.tar.gz (181 kB)
        Installing build dependencies: started
        Installing build dependencies: finished with status 'done'
        Getting requirements to build wheel: started
        Getting requirements to build wheel: finished with status 'done'
        Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml): started
        Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml): finished with status 'done'
      Collecting tomli>=1.1.0 (from maturin<2.0,>=1.0)
        Using cached tomli-2.0.1-py3-none-any.whl (12 kB)
      Building wheels for collected packages: maturin
        Building wheel for maturin (pyproject.toml): started
        Building wheel for maturin (pyproject.toml): finished with status 'error'
        error: subprocess-exited-with-error

        × Building wheel for maturin (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
        │ exit code: 1
        ╰─> [33 lines of output]
            running bdist_wheel
            running build
            running build_py
            creating build
            creating build/lib.cygwin-3.4.7-x86_64-cpython-39
            creating build/lib.cygwin-3.4.7-x86_64-cpython-39/maturin
            copying maturin/import_hook.py -> build/lib.cygwin-3.4.7-x86_64-cpython-39/maturin
            copying maturin/__init__.py -> build/lib.cygwin-3.4.7-x86_64-cpython-39/maturin
            copying maturin/__main__.py -> build/lib.cygwin-3.4.7-x86_64-cpython-39/maturin
            running egg_info
            creating maturin.egg-info
            writing maturin.egg-info/PKG-INFO
            writing dependency_links to maturin.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
            writing requirements to maturin.egg-info/requires.txt
            writing top-level names to maturin.egg-info/top_level.txt
            writing manifest file 'maturin.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
            reading manifest file 'maturin.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
            reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'
            warning: no files found matching '*.json' under directory 'src/python_interpreter'
            writing manifest file 'maturin.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
            running build_ext
            running build_rust
            error: can't find Rust compiler

            If you are using an outdated pip version, it is possible a prebuilt wheel is available for this package but pip is not able to install from it. Installing from the wheel would avoid the need for a Rust compiler.

            To update pip, run:

                pip install --upgrade pip

            and then retry package installation.

            If you did intend to build this package from source, try installing a Rust compiler from your system package manager and ensure it is on the PATH during installation. Alternatively, rustup (available at https://rustup.rs) is the recommended way to download and update the Rust compiler toolchain.
            [end of output]

        note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
        ERROR: Failed building wheel for maturin
      Failed to build maturin
      ERROR: Could not build wheels for maturin, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× pip subprocess to install build dependencies did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> See above for output.

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
```

I also installed Rustup for windows `C:\Users\Administrator\.cargo\bin` and added to PATH from [here](https://rustup.rs/) but nothing

```
Rust path on windows is hereWindows PowerShell
Copyright (C) 2014 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

PS C:\Users\Administrator> cargo --version
cargo 1.71.0 (cfd3bbd8f 2023-06-08)
```

Comment: Do you use the `python3` from Cygwin, or the native Windows build? Your PowerShell message suggests to me that you are somehow mixing Windows and Cygwin executables, and while this is not impossible, this opens the possibility of errors.

Comment: there is no Rust compiler for Cygwin. So you can't install it